# Why does my node not show a lable attached to it on the the graph :

Tags: properties, cypher, identifier

I have used:

```
create(iss_2237:mission{ agency_no:'178', date: '2013-12-14', mission_no:'2237' })

create(iss_3664:mission{ agency_no:'526', date: '2014-01-16', mission_no:'3664' })

create(iss_2356:mission{ agency_no:'167', date: '2014-02-12', mission_no:'2356' })

create(iss_1234:mission{ agency_no:'032', date: '2014-04-16', mission_no:'1234' })
```

all the nodes labeled mission appear blank on the graph; where as my nodes labeled agency have one of the properties appear inside them on the graph.

```
create(jaxa:agency{ title : 'JAXA', country : 'Japan'})

create(esa:agency{ title : 'ESA', country : 'EU'})

create(nasa:agency{ title : 'NAS', country : 'USA'})

create(roskosmos:agency{ title : 'Roskosmos', country : 'Russia'})
```

What am I doing wrong?

[my graph db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5enhn.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be an issue with the styling in the Neo4j Browser.

[This page](http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/#_styling_neo4j_browser_visualization) shows how you can update the styles, including specifying which property is shown in the visualization, specifically:

[image]

You can reset the Neo4j Browser styles with this command:

```
:style reset
```